# How do i split a number in to 3 sections divided by "-" in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have looked through the answers and have found what i am looking for, but i am having trouble adapting it to my query.

I have a number that looks like this.  1110010001.  I want to return it looking like this.  111-001-0001 (or any other divider).

I know how to get 111-0010001 but can anyone tell me how the below code can be adapted to return 111-001-0001 please?

```
SELECT     
CASE
WHEN floor(substr(p.rrnhs, 3,1)) > 0
THEN CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTRING(p.rrnhs, 1, 3), SUBSTRING(p.rrnhs, 3, LENGTH(p.rrnhs)))
ELSE CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTRING(p.rrnhs, 1, 3), SUBSTRING(p.rrnhs, 4, 3ENGTH(p.rrnhs)))
END AS 'NHSNo',
```

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 sections,just add another SUBSTRING segment

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTRING(p.rrnhs, 1, 3), 
                 SUBSTRING(p.rrnhs, 4, 3),SUBSTRING(p.rrnhs, 7, LENGTH(p.rrnhs))) FROM T
```

[Test](http://rextester.com/PEB16588)

Comment: Ah!  I did try that but couldn't get it right.  This worked beautifully though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too

```
select concat(substring('1110010001',1,3),
'-',substring('1110010001',4,3),'-',substring('1110010001',7)) this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the fanciest code, but maybe you could find useful. I just made a stored procedure to achieve your goal in a dynamic way.

With this stored procedure you could parametrize:

- String to split
- Number of characters in each splitted block
- Number of splitted blocks.

  ```
  DELIMITER $$

  CREATE PROCEDURE `stringSplitter`(IN stringToSplit TEXT, IN   numberOfCharactersSplitted INT, IN numberOfSplits INT)
  BEGIN

  DECLARE iteration INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE indexToSplit INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE maxIterations INT;
  DECLARE result TEXT;            
  DECLARE size INT;

  SET maxIterations = LENGTH(stringToSplit) / numberOfCharactersSplitted;
  SET size = LENGTH(stringToSplit);
  SET indexToSplit = 1;
  SET result = ""; 

  WHILE (iteration <= numberOfSplits AND indexToSplit < size) DO       
      SET result = CONCAT(result, substring(stringToSplit,indexToSplit,numberOfCharactersSplitted), '_');
      SET indexToSplit = indexToSplit + numberOfCharactersSplitted;
      SET iteration = iteration + 1;
  END WHILE;

  SET result = CONCAT(result, substring(stringToSplit,indexToSplit,size) );

  SELECT result; 

  END$$

  DELIMITER ;
  ```

**Beware!** I did not tested that much, but I think you could use it with no problem.